# InstallShield execute uninstall custom action

Tags: installshield, uninstallation, custom-action, basic-msi

How do I execute a Custom Action when performing an uninstall?
The Custom Action is within a Basic MSI project and I am using InstallShield 2010 Premier.
I have tried setting the Install UI Sequence to After SetupProgress and Install UI Condition to REMOVE=”ALL”, but the action is not getting called during the uninstall process.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume that you spelled the REMOVE property correctly.  Realize that when you click Uninstall in Add/Remove Programs ( Programs and Features )  that the UI sequence doesn't get executed.  It only gets executed when you click Change.

Also, I don't know what this custom action is doing but if it's making any changes to the state of the system then it should always be scheduled as a deferred custom action in the execute sequence.

You really want to read, and reread until you understand (it took me a few times to get it ) the following:

[Installation Phases and In-Script Execution Options for Custom Actions in Windows Installer](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/index.htm)

Comment: REMOVE is spelt correctly in the property, it was just a typo in the post.
Thanks for the link to Installation Phases, I’ll take a look at the now.